# Gaurd on mixed array type

Tags: typescript

I have an array of loaders which can be either query or proxy. I want to create a gaurd that states that each entry is in the "success" state. I tried this:

```
type LoadedQueryResult = Extract<UseQueryResult, { status: 'success' }>;
type LoadedProxyResult = Extract<UseProxyResult, { status: 'success' }>;
 
function isLoaded<T extends Array<UseQueryResult | UseProxyResult>>(loaders):
  loaders is Array<LoadedQueryResult | LoadedProxyResult>
{
    return loaders.every(loader => loader.status === 'success')
}
```

However it's not working. Is it possible to use guards with mixed array types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather straightforward with generics and intersection types:

```
function isLoaded<T extends {status: string}>(loaders: T[]): loaders is (T & {status: 'success'})[] {
    return loaders.every(loader => loader.status === 'success');
}

/**********************/

type Query = {status: 'success' | 'error', foo: number};
type Proxy = {status: 'success' | 'error', bar: number};

let array: (Query | Proxy)[] = [];

array[0].status; // 'success' | 'error'
if (isLoaded(array)) {
    array[0].status; // 'success'
}
```

<kbd>[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgGTgQwCYFNsA8AKorgB5S5jYqIDeKUmUIKAXIowE4xgDmAXwB8ACgA2WPF3aIiAbQC6ASg4ScuacloiSAMnqNmrDgHIUICBFwoUJgUsX0AUIleIuuFlyRqpKAHS4AG4aAJ7ikhqIALxCiL4a-oYstNFpiGYWVjYmSgDcTgJOTgD0AFQVlVXVNWUlxVChAA64iACKIGExBkwppuaW1raIAD4ZGlxwXCYANIjAcHAcYCAAtgBGGgIFjS2IAAqTZKHdDL3GGQPZw2MmE1OziOuYXMtrm1zbxWKeiC9cmFCHBEHS6Y0OcGODgU3UUBSc-0BcgADAokucUHlECUSpcskMTKNxlxJtMnDBgIgRKgMOpsCJEaElEpnG4-iSkaj0UZMdjcZlBjlCkA)</kbd>